# What kind of shower valve cartridge is this?

Tags: shower, cartridge

I am trying to replace the shower trim kit, and am having trouble identifying this shower valve cartridge. What kind of cartridge is this?

#### Assembled

[image]

### Disassembled

[image]

[image]

Comment: In order to identify it we need high quality and proper illumination

Comment: [https://allthumbsdiy.com/plumbing/how-to-identify-a-faucet-brand](https://allthumbsdiy.com/plumbing/how-to-identify-a-faucet-brand)

Comment: Now that you have it in hand, go to a real plumbing store. (There’s a possibility that the big box stores would have it, but they might not.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Delta ball valve faucet. The ball in question is Delta 212 ball. The deck plate has a patent number 3056418. The whole trim kit can also be found under "Delta 600 Series" name.

My original intent was to replace the assembly (it was leaking a bit) and replace clear knob handle with a lever handle. The orignal 212 ball is not compatible with Delta's lever handles, but there is a RP20111 conversion ball with a compatible RP17443 lever handle.

All assembly parts:

- RP17443 shower handle
- RP5883 deck plate
- RP196 deck plate screws
- RP1050 cap
- RP5893 sleeve
- RP20111 conversion ball
- RP4993 seats & springs
- RP188 cam and packing.

(Steve Wellens's comment under the question showed me the right direction: [How to Identify a Faucet Brand](https://allthumbsdiy.com/plumbing/how-to-identify-a-faucet-brand).)